# Replace CarriageReturn Using Replace in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to VBA and want to accomplish something pretty simple but am confused as to why this is not working. I am reading in lines from a file and if opened in notepad++, each line has a CRLF at the end. I would like to just remove the CR. In notepad++ I can do a replaceall, replacing CRLF with LF and things work great. However, the test I have in VBA right now is not doing this correctly. Below is an example of a string I'm dealing with in Notepad++:

Summary - I went for a walk in the parkCRLF

I want the string to become, Summary - I went for a walk in the parkLF

I am writing out to a file as a test in order to see if its working. Below is my code:

```
    Do While Not txtStream.AtEndOfStream

    str = txtStream.ReadLine
    edited = Replace(str, Chr(13) & Chr(10), Chr(10))
    stream.WriteLine (edited)

Loop

txtStream.Close
```

The code is being executed without error but the CRLF is still at the end of each line in the newly written file...Maybe I'm missing something obviously but the replace does not seem to be picking up on what I'm searching for. Any help or advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Even figuring out if the end of the line ends with a CRLF would be a step in the right direction at this point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- WriteLine automatically places an end of line after your string
- You should replace it with @Mark's suggestion: `stream.Write(edited)`
- This performs better:

  `stream.Write(Replace(txtStream.ReadAll, vbCrLf, vbLf))`

  or

  `stream.Write(Replace(txtStream.ReadAll, vbCr, vbLf))`

.

Details about [ReadAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t58aa4dd(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much Paul. Using the vbCr and vbCrLf constants worked!

Answer (score 3):

You are reading a line so it will remove the new line characters. Your replace statement has nothing to do. You are then writing a line which will add new line characters.

Also, you aren't closing the output stream in the code sample you provided.

You will want something like this:

```
 Do While Not txtStream.AtEndOfStream
      str = txtStream.ReadLine
      stream.Write str & Chr(10)
 Loop

 txtStream.Close
 stream.Close
```